# Unhandled Promise rejection when rejecting Promise in Angular 2

Tags: angular, promise

I am currently trying to implement my own Promise to be used inside Angular 2. If I `reject` the promise, I'll get an `Error: Uncaught (in promise): nope(…)`, but only on the first Promise to be rejected.

It's `Angular 2.0.0-rc.4`, but I noticed this in other behaviors. My question is, is this an error in my understanding of Promises, or is this a bug that should be reported to the Angular project?

Sample code:

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {bootstrap} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'
@Component({
    template: "TestComponent"
})
class TestComponent {
}
bootstrap(TestComponent, []);

let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("create promise");
    reject("nope");
});
console.log("setting up");
p.then(r => console.log("then: " + r));
p.catch(e => console.log("reject: " + e));
console.log("setup done");
```

Console (Google Chrome 51.0.2704.106, Linux 64 bit):

```
create promise
setting up
setup done
reject: nope
Angular 2 is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
Unhandled Promise rejection: nope ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: nope
Error: Uncaught (in promise): nope(…)
```

Comment: are you using es6 promise or you have your own implementation?

Comment: The implementation is `ZoneAwarePromise` from `zone.js`, as far as I can tell. That's why I think it's related to Angular.

Comment: The title is somehow misleading. 'implementing own Promise in Angular 2' unambiguously suggests that there is homebrew Promise implementation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It should be

```
p
.then(r => console.log("then: " + r))
.catch(e => console.log("reject: " + e));
```

`p.then(...)` alone creates unhandled chain, this bothers Zone.js. If you have dealt with Bluebird's 'unhandled rejections', you may already know the rules.

Comment: Thanks, I just found that out when it made "click" in my brain when I was thinking about why the solution from Thierry Templier worked.

Answer (score 3):

You could the following:

```
let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  console.log("create promise");
  reject("nope");
});
console.log("setting up");
p.then(r => console.log("then: " + r), // <-----
   e => console.log("reject: " + e));
```

Comment: Actually, this works, thanks, I never thought about that. But why is it wrong to use the `.catch` callback?

Comment: It's because `catch` is a promise handler (then or catch) and they don't stop chaining...