# Get zone-free window methods with Zone.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, zonejs

Can zone-free `window` methods (`setTimeout`, etc) be accessed somehow with loaded Zone.js ? Does Zone.js expose the original unpatched methods?

The example of possible use case is Angular 2 app that has some problems with Angular 2 Material data binding and needs to call un-zoned `setTimeout` as temporary but instant workaround - before the issue will be fixed properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you need to leverage NgZone and its `runOutsideAngular` method for this. Here is a sample:

```
constructor(private ngZone:NgZone) {
}

setTimeout(() => {
  this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
    // do something
  });
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks, excellent, this covers the given case. Any insights on how Zone.js can be avoided/unloaded at all? [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38265963/unhandled-promise-rejection-when-rejecting-promise-in-angular-2) illustrates that Zone may introduce global side effects for non-Angular applications. While catching the rejections is a good habit, ES6 promise isn't supposed to complain on unhandled ones, and it seems that there's no way to shut Zone.js up, like it could be done with `Promise.onUnhandledRejection(noop)` for Bluebird.

Comment: You're welcome! I think that you can't with Angular2 since Zone.js triggers change detection. Without zones, nothing will be updated in templates ;-) I saw you answer on the question ;-)

Comment: It looks like `setTimeout` here will still trigger additional unwanted ChangeDetection cycle

Answer (score 7):

yes, basically the native method can be access by

```
target[Zone['__symbol__'](methodName)]
```

or 
    target['**zone_symbol**'methodName]

such as

```
window['__zone_symbol__setTimeout']
```

and you can access NativePromise by

```
window['__zone_symbol__Promise']
```

I will make a list later.

Comment: Good one on `Zone['__symbol__'](methodName)`!

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the answer, the original methods can be reached with `__zone_symbol__` prefix, as of Zone.js 0.6.12 (may be a subject to change).

I.e. `window.__zone_symbol__setTimeout`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I do like this:

```
const w: any = window
export const setTimeoutNoZone: typeof setTimeout = w.__zone_symbol__setTimeout
export const setIntervalNoZone: typeof setInterval = w.__zone_symbol__setInterval
```

And then use them in places where ChangeDetection is not needed:

```js
setTimeoutNoZone(() => { ... }, 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also take care for Promise::then

I've implemented the following util functions in my project

```
function jb_new_NativePromise(cb) {
  if (window && window.__zone_symbol__Promise) {
    var res = new __zone_symbol__Promise(cb);
    res.then = res.__zone_symbol__then;
    return res;
  }

  return new Promise(cb);
}

function jb_NativePromise_resolve(obj) {
  return jb_new_NativePromise(resolve=>resolve(obj))
}

function jb_native_delay(ms) {
  var set_timeout = window && window.__zone_symbol__setTimeout || setTimeout;
  return jb_new_NativePromise(resolve => set_timeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's the point of the code above. Does `new __zone_symbol__Promise(...).then` method really use zones and should be overridden?