# Node.js UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning even after catching it

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, async-await, es6-promise

I'm using Node 7.2.1 with the new **async/await** feature. I'm also using the Native ES6 Promises with mongoose like this -

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
```

My code flow is like this -

```
async function getFollowers(){
    try {
        const followers = await User.getFollowersFromMongo(req.params.userId);
        res.send(followers);
    } catch (err) {
        winston.error('Printing Error = ', err);
        res.status(400).send({success: false, error: err});
    }
}

UserSchema.statics.getFollowersFromMongo = async(userId) => {
    try {
        let aggregateQuery = []; //some syntactical error in mongo query to produce exception

        const followers = await User.aggregate(aggregateQuery);
        return followers.map(follower => follower.followerData);
    }
    catch (err) {
        return Promise.reject(err);
    }
};
```

This code works absolutely fine. Problem arises when there's some error produced. So I purposely modified my *mongoose* query so that *MongoDB* would throw an error.

Now MongoDB, as expected throws an error which is perfectly caught by my code and returned to the client with a 400 error code.

The Problem is that even though the error(intentional) has been caught by me, *Node.js* still gives me this warning -

```
error:  Printing Error = MongoError: path option to $unwind stage should be prefixed with a '$': followerData
at Function.MongoError.create (/home/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:31:11)
at /home/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:483:72
at authenticateStragglers (/home/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:429:16)
at Connection.messageHandler (/home/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:463:5)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:317:22)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
at TCP.onread (net.js:551:20)

GET /user/385/followers 400 39.868 ms - 263

(node:10158) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): MongoError: path option to $unwind stage should be prefixed with a '$': followerData
(node:10158) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

As it can be seen my request has returned the 400 status and my error log has also been printed from the initial method's catch block but *Node.js* is still saying that the error message is not handled.

Why is it saying this even after the same error has been caught?

**Update -** Thanks to @dvlsg and @Bergi, the bug has been fixed in version 4.7.5

Comment: My guess would be because you're catching it with a try/catch instead of .catch().

Comment: @KevinB but isn't that how async/await handles errors?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40500490/what-is-unhandled-promise-rejection

Comment: Not using a `.catch()` doesn't seem to be the problem. [This](https://gist.github.com/jyotman94/0fcf0ce4298760854b99a13f53e17dd7) is another example using the same approach which doesn't produce the `unhandled` stack trace.

Comment: The reason this example doesn't have an unhandled error is because `caller1` will `catch` the `Promise.reject(err)` from `caller2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There definitely appears to be something strange with how mongoose aggregate plays with async/await. Seems like a bug, to me. If it is, it should definitely be reported to mongoose.

Thankfully, there is an easy work around:

```
const followers = await User.aggregate(aggregateQuery).exec();
```

Adding the explicit `.exec()` allows me to catch the aggregate pipeline error as expected.

---

I think the underlying issue adding to the confusion here is that there is an additional `Promise` floating around which is being rejected and not handled. Because technically, you *are* handling the expected rejection here correctly. Otherwise you wouldn't see that `Printing error = ...` being logged.

Here's what I believe is happening --

- You `await User.aggregate()`
- `Aggregate#then()` is called through `await` working with `thenables` (I think)
- `Aggregate#exec()` is called internally by `Aggregate#then()`

  - Note that [a callback is provided](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/09a1d72178eb9cb0873e457787e10e235cead07a/lib/aggregate.js#L609) to `exec()`
- A new `Promise` inside `Aggregate#exec()` is [created](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/09a1d72178eb9cb0873e457787e10e235cead07a/lib/aggregate.js#L562), and [will be rejected](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/09a1d72178eb9cb0873e457787e10e235cead07a/lib/aggregate.js#L419)

  - *This* is the unhandled `Promise`, I believe.
- Since a callback is provided to `Aggregate#exec()` from `Aggregate#then()`, the `Error` inside `Aggregate#exec()` will be [provided to the callback](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/09a1d72178eb9cb0873e457787e10e235cead07a/lib/aggregate.js#L565-L567)
- Inside the callback in `Aggregate#then()`, a newly [created](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/09a1d72178eb9cb0873e457787e10e235cead07a/lib/aggregate.js#L608) `Promise` is rejected

  - I believe this `Promise` is handled as expected, since it is the return from `Aggregate#then()`

I think I can confirm my suspicions by commenting out [this line](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/09a1d72178eb9cb0873e457787e10e235cead07a/lib/aggregate.js#L568) in the mongoose `Aggregate` definition. This will prevent the unhandled rejection handler from being hit. Not that I'm suggesting to do that, by the way. That's just additional evidence, not a solution, since now I just have an unrejected `Promise` floating around.

---

Here is a minimal-ish way to reproduce the uncaught rejection in a self contained bit of code, to be run with `node --harmony-async-await` (tested on node `v7.2.1`)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/temp');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: 'string'
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

async function run() {
  try {
    await User.aggregate([]);
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log('caught expected error:', err);
  }
}

run();
```

Comment: If this is the case, it definitely should be reported to mongoose as a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the links to the source, it's as I suspected. The fix should be to change the `then` method to a simple `function(onfulfill, onreject) { return this.exec().then(onfulfill, onreject); }`, [avoiding the `Promise` constructor antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572) that unnecessarily creates a second promise via the `exec` callback. Do you want to open the GH issue?

Comment: Sure, I can do that.

Comment: Issue available [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4824).

Comment: Yes applying `.exec()` at the end of the query doesn't produce the error. I'll follow  the github issue and if your reasoning is proved right then I'll gladly accept this answer.