# Issue with npm require

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, package.json, nightmare

I'm running a Nightmare.js script, and within it I'm trying to `require` lodash
(installed locally with npm, in node_modules, registered in package.json).

index.js :

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var _ = require('lodash');

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

function getElms(elm) {
    var elsm =  document.querySelectorAll(elm);
    return _.map(elsm, function(elem){ return elem.innerHTML; });
} 

var someWebsite = new Nightmare({ show: false })
  .goto( ***some url*** )
  .wait(getRandomInt(2500, 5000))
  .evaluate(function () {

      var elsm =  document.querySelectorAll(***some selector***);
      return _.map(elsm, function(elem){ return elem.innerHTML; });

      // return getElms(***some selector***);


  }).then(function(linkstexts) {
    console.log(linkstexts)
  });
```

- but I'm getting this:

  UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): _ is not defined

  - similar issue if I uncomment and use `return getElms(***some selector***);`

This is package.json

```
{
  "name": "nightxp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "nightmare": "^2.10.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

[image]

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

I tried passing the lodash to the browser scope, and completing with `catch()`,
but somehow the lodash variable still isnt being passed to the scope (example with hackernews):

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var lodash = require('lodash');

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min; 
}

var facebook = new Nightmare({ show: false })
  .goto('https://news.ycombinator.com')
  .wait(getRandomInt(5500, 6000))
  .evaluate(  (lodash) => {
      var elsm =  document.querySelectorAll('tr td.title a.storylink');
      return lodash.map(elsm, function(elem){ return elem.innerHTML; });
   }, lodash).then(function(titles) {
    console.log(titles)
  }).catch(function (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
  });
```

and this is what I get:

```
C:\Projects\nightmare>set DEBUG=nightmare & node index.js
  nightmare queuing process start +0ms
  nightmare queueing action "goto" for https://news.ycombinator.com +4ms
  nightmare queueing action "wait" +2ms
  nightmare queueing action "evaluate" +0ms
  nightmare running +1ms
Error: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

Comment: It might be because you don't have `.catch(...)` after you call `.then(...)`

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41180264/3498950

Comment: The unhandled promise rejection is because you don't have a catch. But the real questions is why `_` is undefined in the first place. Are you sure you ran `npm install` and it's actually in node_modules?

Comment: @spencer.sm thing is, when I wasn't looping over an array & was extracting just a single element, it was okay.

Even without .catch()

Comment: @Mark_M yes, lodash is in node_modules. I ran `npm install lodash --save`

Comment: If it means anything, I am on Windows.

Comment: Have you tried adding `.catch(...)` ?

Comment: When I try to uncomment the `getElms(` line, I get error that getElms is undefined.

(I only added two lines above commented getElms call because of that, to see if I can call the code from the function directly)

Comment: No, node script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run

```
var someWebsite = new Nightmare({ show: false })
.evaluate(function () {
/* ... */
}
```

You are now in browser scope — you can think of `Nightmare.evaluate` as running the contained code in the context of an independent browser, which means your global scope, including `_` is not available.

See here for a bit more info and some tips on passing data into the scope:

https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/89

https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/333

Edit:

While you can pass simple values into evaluate from the node context, you can't pass complex values with functions and methods. This is because the arguments are serialize in transit and this is difficult with functions. Here's an issue that explains it a bit:

https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/349

In this particular case it seems like the easiest thing to do is to work without lodash, which these days isn't hard. For example:

```
var facebook = new Nightmare({ show: false })
.goto('https://news.ycombinator.com')
.wait(getRandomInt(5500, 6000))
.evaluate(  () => {
    var elsm =  document.querySelectorAll('tr td.title a.storylink');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(elsm, elem => elem.innerHTML)
})
.then(function(titles) {
    console.log("title", titles)
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
});
```

Comment: I tried with this, but it still says it cant read property 'map' of undefined

`  .evaluate(  (lodash) => {
   var elsm =  document.querySelectorAll(***someselector***);
   return lodash.map(elsm, function(elem){ return elem.innerHTML; });
   }, lodash) `

Comment: @tonino.j - see edit, looks like it's not going to be easy to use lodash like this.

Comment: Do you have idea what may be the way to load things (like functions / libraries) into browser context?

Or is the only way to just snatch and return a string and process it outside?