# Overwriting file in typescript

Tags: angularjs, node.js, typescript, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I run the test and the first time the test is done. When I run the test the second time I get a message like below. I tried removing the file from this folder,
But there is no such possibility. Does anyone know how to solve this?
The file chromedriver_2_33.zip is the chromedriver.exe file. I am trying to remove chromedriver_2.33.exe but can not

```
webpack: Compiled successfully.
[14:17:49] I/update - chromedriver: file exists C:\Users\teste2e\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver_2.33.zip
[14:17:49] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_2.33.zip
(node:17500) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 108): Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\teste2e\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver.exe' -> 'C:\Users\teste2e\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver_2.33.exe'
```

Comment: It has been described in the another issue [Take a look there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40500490/what-is-unhandled-promise-rejection)

Comment: It seems to me that this is not the same problem