# How to add schema folder to ajv

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajv

I have some json schemas in a folder ..src/schema/jsonschemas
And I have my node js scripts in a folder ../src/nodescripts/script.js

```
let Ajv = require('ajv');
let ajv = new Ajv();
jschema = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("../src/schema/file.json", 'utf8'));
let validate = ajv.compile(jschema);
```

But i get the following error:
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2).
The cause is the $ref on the json schema(but i  ndeed the $ref part. Any Ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an unhandled promise rejection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40500490/what-is-an-unhandled-promise-rejection)

Comment: @GuilhermeMartin its not a duplicate because the error or warning occurs because of the ajv.compile because i am using a $ref in a thoer folder that the ajv cant resolve. the link you posted has nothing to do with my problem...

Comment: in python we have something like 
from jsonschema import RefResolver
resolver = RefResolver("...", None). Is there something for node js to?

Comment: @Sken How do you know the cause of the error is the $ref in your schema? Can you wrap this section of your code in a try/catch and share the error message with us?

Comment: @JustinMoser because  when i delete the $ref then it works.