# Keeps giving me Unhandled Promise Rejection Warning and I'm unable to spot the error

Tags: javascript, promise, discord, discord.js, unhandled

**Here's my code, I have a command handler btw.**

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const token = 'hidden';
const sqlite = require('sqlite3').verbose();
const dayno = '0';
const PREFIX = '$';
const fs = require('fs');



bot.on('message', (message) => { 
    let userid = message.author.id;

if (message.author.bot || !message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;
    if(message.author.bot)return;
    let db = new sqlite.Database('./database.db', sqlite.OPEN_READWRITE );


            bot.commands = new Discord.Collection();

            const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
            for(const file of commandFiles){
                const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

                bot.commands.set(command.name, command);


            if (message.author.bot || !message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) 
            return;

            let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
        switch(args[0]){

            case 'help':

                bot.commands.get('help').execute(message, args);    
            break;

            case 'getreports':

                if(message.member.roles.cache.find(r => r.name
                    === "Developers")) return message.channel('You are not authorized to use this command.')
                    bot.commands.get('getreports').execute(message, args);         

            break;

            case 'getreportsof':


                if(message.member.roles.cache.find(r => r.name
                    === "Developer")){
                    bot.commands.get('getreportsof').execute(message, args);   
                }else{

                message.reply('You are not authorized to use this command.')

                }    

            break;



        };

    };


});

bot.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log('Duncan Online');
    bot.user.setActivity('$help', {type: "LISTENING"}).catch(console.error);
    let db = new sqlite.Database('./database.db', sqlite.OPEN_READWRITE | sqlite.OPEN_CREATE)
    db.run('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data(userid INTEGER NOT NULL, reports INTEGER NOT NULL)')
});


bot.login(token);
```

**Here's the error :**

```
(node:12456) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\HP_Omen\Desktop\Testing\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:170:25)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:12456) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a 
catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag 
`--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:12456) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything in the code that you have provided that would directly cause the error. That is most likely coming from your commands.

For each of the switch cases, use something like this:

```js
bot.commands.get('help').execute(message, args).catch(console.error)
```

The `catch` should help you to locate the error. If not, add `.catch(console.error)` to wherever you call async functions (ones that return a promise) in your commands.

---

I personally find it a lot easier and readable to use [`async` functions and `await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) instead of `then` and `catch`, so you could also refactor your code to something like this:

```js
// commands/help.js
module.exports = {
    name: 'help',
    async execute(message, args) {
        // note how I use await here 
        await message.channel.send('some useful help message');
    }
};

// your main file (probably index.js or something)
bot.on('message', async (message) => {
    try {
        // rest of code...
        switch (args[0]) {
            case 'help':
                // use await here as well so that the errors get caught
                await bot.commands.get('help').execute(message, args);
                break;
            // rest of commands
        }
    } catch (error) {
        // log all errors
        console.error(error)
    }
});
```

---

For more information on unhandled promise rejections, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41180264/8289918).

Answer (score 0):

**I had forgotten to close this:**

```
            for(const file of commandFiles){
                const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

                bot.commands.set(command.name, command);
```

**It works just fine  like this:**

```
        for(const file of commandFiles){
            const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

            bot.commands.set(command.name, command);

}
```

**anyways, I thank you for your answer.**