# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning error when accessing Faker images?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-promise, faker

I am a learner of JavaScript here. I have a file called `downloadFakeImage.js` with the following script:

```js
const faker = require('faker');
const axios = require('axios');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const url = [];
// Generate 1000 fake url from faker
for (let i=0; i<1000; i++) {
    url.push(faker.image.fashion());
}

// Download 1000 user photos to local image folder
for (let i=0; i<url.length; i++) {
    // path for image storage
    const imagePath = path.join(__dirname, './image', `${i}.jpg`);
    axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: url[i],
        responseType: 'stream'
    })
        .then((response) => {
            response.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(imagePath));
        });
}
```

The goal of this script is to generate 1000 fake fashion images to a folder named `image`. When I run `node downloadFakeImage.js` in my terminal, only some of the images get to save into the folder. My terminal show whole brunch of the following error message:

[Error message from the terminal that I received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQGvE.png)

I think this might be related to an async issue, can someone teaches me how to refractor my script to make it work?

**Update:**

I refactored my code to the following and I was able to generate some images, but I still cannot generate 1000 images. For the first 300 images, it was running ok and then it failed.

```
const faker = require('faker');
const axios = require('axios');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

async function seedImage() {
    const url = [];
    // Generate 1000 fake url from faker
    for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        url.push(faker.image.fashion());
    }

    // Download 1000 user photos to local image folder
    for (let i = 0; i < url.length; i++) {
        // path for image storage
        const imagePath = await path.join(__dirname, './image', `${i}.jpg`);
        axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: url[i],
            responseType: 'stream'
        })
            .then((response) => {
                response.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(imagePath));
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
}

seedImage();
```

Comment: Add a `catch` callback to the Promise chain, do whatever with the rejected Promise error, or drop and ignore it. Does this answer your question? [What is an unhandled promise rejection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40500490/what-is-an-unhandled-promise-rejection)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an unhandled promise rejection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40500490/what-is-an-unhandled-promise-rejection)

Comment: you do realise you're trying to make 1000 simultaneous requests, right? perhaps the endpoint is saying "no way", and giving you errors, which you don't catch

Comment: I was able to catch the error using the help from below. However, I wasn't able to figure out how to solve this issue from reading the error. It is probably my script is not written correctly. I might have to learn how to use Unsplash API instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a catch block to handle errors as below:

```js
const faker = require('faker');
const axios = require('axios');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const url = [];
// Generate 1000 fake url from faker
for (let i=0; i<1000; i++) {
    url.push(faker.image.fashion());
}

// Download 1000 user photos to local image folder
for (let i=0; i<url.length; i++) {
    // path for image storage
    const imagePath = path.join(__dirname, './image', `${i}.jpg`);
    axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: url[i],
        responseType: 'stream'
    })
        .then((response) => {
            response.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(imagePath));
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was able to catch the error using this method. However,  the error message is not helpful for me to understand how to debug it. Thank you though.

Comment: I think the problems are you request too much to server. You can reduce the number URL to 3 for the test or set the delay time for each request by use *timeout* function.

Comment: I updated the post with my refactored code. The script running okay for the first 300 images and then it failed.

Comment: I think the script should work for a small amount of images. However, my goal is to get a large amount of images.