# Code working on my machine but not in hosting

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, instagram

I have used the "instagram-private-api" npm package to change the bio of my intagram profile over time. the code is working on my local machine but not on my ubuntu hosting(azure).

Here is the code:

```
const { IgApiClient } = require("instagram-private-api")
const ig = new IgApiClient()

const USERNAME = "username"
const PASSWORD = "pass"

ig.state.generateDevice(USERNAME)

const main = async () => {
  await ig.simulate.preLoginFlow()
  await ig.account.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD)

  // log out of Instagram when done
  process.nextTick(async () => await ig.simulate.postLoginFlow())

  // change the bio
  await ig.account.setBiography("testing stuff...")
}

main()
```

Here is the error that comes:

```
(node:1470) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: IgResponseError: POST /api/v1/accounts/msisdn_header_bootstrap/ - 302 Found; 
    at Request.handleResponseError (/home/mamba/node_modules/instagram-private-api/dist/core/request.js:126:16)
    at Request.send (/home/mamba/node_modules/instagram-private-api/dist/core/request.js:54:28)
(node:1470) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:1470) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Please Help me with this problem, TIA!

Answer (score 0):

Here all the async function written in the given program may or may not return a value . Thus in an event of not receiving any response from the async function a **.catch(...)** block is expected .
The lack of the  **.catch(..)** is the reason you are getting the **unhandled promise rejection  error** .

You can use the following :

```
.catch((error)=>{
//enter you logic here
console.log("unhandled promice rejection occured");
});
```

You have to add this at the end of the async functions .

Thus in an event of event of failure the **.catch(...)** will catch the error and you can also add additional logic when such events occur .

You can refer the following article :

[Promises in Node.js (stackabuse.com)](https://stackabuse.com/promises-in-node-js/)

[Node.js Process unhandledPromiseRejection Event - GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-process-unhandledpromiserejection-event/#:%7E:text=The%20unhandledRejection%20event%20is%20emitted%20whenever%20a%20promise,handler%20to%20handle%20it%20in%20the%20promise%20chain.?msclkid=792022fea99711eca88d6c7e9f4d5b13)

[javascript - What is an unhandled promise rejection? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40500490/what-is-an-unhandled-promise-rejection#:%7E:text=This%20is%20when%20a%20Promise%20is%20completed%20with,the%20root%20error%20handler%20to%20produce%20that%20output.?msclkid=d6e096f7a9a311ec9e945bcb775e28fe)

[What is an unhandled promise rejection? | TOMDUFFYTECH.COM](https://tomduffytech.com/unhandled-promise-rejection/?msclkid=f4bef649aa2c11ecbac1b945677b00ab)