# NgZone no longer works

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ngzone

My NgZone seems to no longer work.. I'm building an app using Ionic, Angular, and Firebase.

It produces an error:

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Missing Command Error ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Missing Command Error undefined

I've had it in my project for months, with no problems at all, and I use it in quite a few places, but all of a sudden it no longer works.

I import it normally:

```
import { Component, Input, NgZone, ViewChild, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
```

in the constructor

```
public zone: NgZone,
```

and then reference it like so:

```
this.zone = new NgZone({});

this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  this.zone.run(() => {
    if (user) {
      this.rootPage = HomePage
    } else {
      this.rootPage = LoginPage
      console.log("Not logged in")
    }
    this.splashScreen.hide();
  });
});
```

But it doesn't work anymore...

My `package.json` calls the following dependency:

`"zone.js": "0.8.18"`

Any ideas what this might mean or what I should do? Thanks!

Comment: what version of angular are you using?

Comment: @PatricioVargas I'm on `ng-version: 6.1.1`

Comment: can you try to change it in the constructor to private instead of public?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38265963/unhandled-promise-rejection-when-rejecting-promise-in-angular-2

Comment: @PatricioVargas thanks, but I'm not sure how that is helpful?

Comment: please remove this line this.zone = new NgZone({});

Comment: Hey Jane, btw why do you need to use "zone" explicitly in here? Which version of AngularFire are you using? normally that should not require you to leverage "zone" as responses from firebase should be triggering change detection automatically.

Answer (score 1):

please try to follow these steps:

1- import NgZone
`import { Component, NgZone, OnInit} from '@angular/core';`

2- in constractor inside class 
 `constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {}`

3- remove this line `this.zone = new NgZone({});`

4- leave these lines of code as it

```
`this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  this.zone.run(() => {
    if (user) {
      this.rootPage = HomePage
    } else {
      this.rootPage = LoginPage
      console.log("Not logged in")
    }
    this.splashScreen.hide();
  });
});`
```

try now....